# Parse array of MongoDB collection in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, mongodb

I cab able to parse this array through for loop

You can see the console log here.

[image]

Parsing with role_code in JavaScript is like

```
for (doctor in data.user.userType){
  console.log(data.user.userType[doctor].role_code) }
```

But I'm unable to parse a (clinic address) which is in an array in an array in array

Log here

[image]

sorry for the editing clinic array obeject is hidden behind the line

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
$.each(data.rows,function(i,v){
  $.each(v.current_clinic_detail,function(x,y){
     console.log(y.clinicAddress);
  });
});
```